# Unit testing explicitly dispatching WebhookReceived event is not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-cashier

I am building a Laravel application. I am using Laravel Cashier to handle subscription in my application. I am writing unit test for the Stripe Webhook creating a custom event listener for that.

I have an event listener like this:

```
class StripeEventListener
{
    /**
     * Create the event listener.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  object  $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(WebhookReceived $event)
    {
        if ($event->payload['type'] === 'invoice.payment_succeeded') {
            // Handle the incoming event...
        }
        // TODO: write unit test for this event.
        if ($event->payload['type'] === 'customer.subscription.updated') {
            // Handle the incoming event...
            // handleCustomerSubscriptionUpdated
            if ($user = $this->getUserByStripeId($event->payload['data']['object']['customer'])) {
                $data = $event->payload['data']['object'];
                if (
                    isset($data['status']) &&
                    ($data['status'] === StripeSubscription::STATUS_INCOMPLETE_EXPIRED ||
                    $data['status'] == StripeSubscription::STATUS_INCOMPLETE)
                ) {
                    if (! $user->payment_method_needs_updating) {
                        $user->payment_method_needs_updating = true;
                        $user->save();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    protected function getUserByStripeId($stripeId)
    {
        return Cashier::findBillable($stripeId);
    }
}
```

Then I bind that to WebhookReceived event in the EventServiceProvider like this:

```
protected $listen = [
        WebhookReceived::class => [
            StripeEventListener::class
        ],
        Registered::class => [
            SendEmailVerificationNotification::class,
        ],
    ];
```

I am unit testing the listener dispatching the WebhookReceived event like this:

```
WebhookReceived::dispatch([
            .... mock data
        ]);
```

But I am getting this error:

```
   Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException 

  Target class [events] does not exist.

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:879
    875▕ 
    876▕         try {
    877▕             $reflector = new ReflectionClass($concrete);
    878▕         } catch (ReflectionException $e) {
  ➜ 879▕             throw new BindingResolutionException("Target class [$concrete] does not exist.", 0, $e);
    880▕         }
```

How can I fix it or how can I unit test it?

Comment: Why do you build your own webhook listener when Laravel Cashier catches everything you need? The default endpoint of Laravel Cashier is **www.yourwebsite.com/stripe/webhook** and it handles everything you need. If you are on local server you can use NGROK to open a tunnel for your localhost. Provide the link that NGROK gives you and use it as an endpoint in stripe dashboard.

Comment: I am customing an event. I am not creating my own event. WebhookReceived is the Cashier built-in event. It also mentions on the doc to do that if we need to do customisation.